# I am unable to close my database in indexedDB(Firefox)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexeddb

I am trying to close my database in `indexedDB`. Firefox is the browser I am using for my development. When i try to create new store I am facing the error that my database is open. so guide me to solve this issue. Below code I am using to close the database for previous store.

> Error:
>   The operation failed because the requested database object could not be found. For example, an object store did not exist but was being opened.

Code:

```
transaction.oncomplete = function (event) {
    db.close();
};
```

Comment: what version of firebase are you using?

Comment: That error message is used for the NotFoundError, which is thrown by the objectStore(), deleteObjectStore(), index(), deleteIndex(), and transaction() methods on various objects. Can you confirm the method call that is throwing the exception?

Comment: i am using version 1

Comment: Please post more of the surrounding code